# ASP.NET - Who can use one web application and "host" many sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I've a personal project, and the logic layer and database is equal, but I've two domains that the only thing that changes is the URL, and the master page.

What I need is a simple system to recognize the URL and show the correct site master, because I what use the same database with the configuration of ASP.NET tables, stored procedure and so one.

The most similar thing I've saw, it's the DNN portal system, but I don't need all the features, like separate login system.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something along these lines will get you what you need:

In IIS, point both URLs to the same virtual directory, so they are both being served from the same place -

Add a `PreInit` event to read the URL then load a MasterPage accordingly:

```
void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  if(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("mysite.com")) 
  { 
    this.MasterPageFile = "master page file goes here"; 
  } 
}
```

Hope that gets you in the right direction!

Comment: Another simple and elegant solution! :)
Thanks, that's solve my problem too, because I've an BasePage for every pages! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the master page dynamic.  The host name can be found in:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]
```

You can use this inside the master page to change its output.

Comment: Simple and elegant! :)
That's it that a search for!!!

You recommend to use this trip on Global, wide master page, or page pre init?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would take it one step further and abstracting everything away that differ and then use dependency injection to resolve what you need.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but it should work. If you start by using a dependency injector, like Ninject for example, that is one step forward. After that you can register the server specific components per request, if you are hosting on the same web server. Use interfaces that abstracts the parts that should differ and then implement one for each company. It is somewhat hard to explain, but if you read about Ninject and other depency injector framework you might figure it out on your own.

Comment: Thanks for your explain! :) I'm loking for it!